Custom font in streamlit correctly render from laptop but not from mobile
I'm developing a streamlit app and I want to use a custom font. I found some tutorials on how to do that using some css, and it works locally. I also deployed my app using Streamlit Cloud, and when I access the app from a browser in my laptop, the custom font renders correctly, while when I access the app from my mobile, the custom font does not render. I used Firefox both from laptop and mobile, and on the mobile I also tried Chrome, to no avail.
Below are pictures of the current situation:
from laptop:

from mobile:

I'm not an expert in using css, and I expect that the app should behave in the same way since the code is the same and I'm using the same browser.
The code is freely accessible in this repo. In particular, note:

the css file;
the app entrypoint, where I put the hack to read the css and use it to set the font for the whole app;
the page I shared pictures of;
I loaded the ttf file in the same folder where I put the css.


Your CSS contains only a local font reference local("Typo") - the browser will only render this font if it's installed on the device. You need to add a relative URL like url('Typo.ttf') format('truetype'). For better loading times you should consider using the more compact woff2 or woff format.

Please always include and update relevant code to your question - your CSS link is already dead. Please keep in mind the idea of SO is to provide valid solutions based on reproducible issues. In other words: all parts of the code should remain available for future users struggling with similar problems.

you are right, i fixed the link


Your CSS contains only a local font reference local("Typo") - the browser will only render this font if it's installed on the device. You need to add a relative URL like url('Typo.ttf') format('truetype').

-- herrstrietzel

For better loading times you should consider using the more compact woff2 or woff format.

-- herrstrietzel
Best service for this is fontsquirrel's webfont generator, where you'll get following CSS:
@font-face {
    font-family: 'typoregular';
    src: url('typo-webfont.eot');
    src: url('typo-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* to support ancient browsers like IE */
         url('typo-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('typo-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('typo-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

in a zip file containing the necessary files.

Truetype is probably the [best upported font format - unless you need to support very ancient browsers. .eot (Internet Explorer only)and .svg (deprecated and not supported by chromium and firefox) can safely be removed

Tnank you very much! But actually this solution isn't working. I got it to work combining your proposed solution (using only one of the font file extensions was enough) and an adaptation of the code in the this link to copy the font files to the /static/assests directory. Anyway, my solution only works locally, not when deployed (it gives PermissionDenied error). Code on github is updated.

@mattiatantardini: pardon me, but I disagree with the linked streamlit recommendation: better avoid any local() references completely - while the idea is apparently great (to avoid unnecessary remote font requests) in reality it's one of the most common sources of inconsistent font rendering – we can't really trust the browser to choose the right locally (OS based) candidate. Besides keep in mind the browser doesn't care about the used framework - so better check the final output via dev tools and correct file paths/Urls to get the desired output.

Thanks for the explanation. What if I have the font file only locally and the font cannot be fetched from remote server, nor I cannot load it into my own server (which I tried to do but gives me permission error, since it is a streamlit cloud machine)? I looked online for solution about loading the font to a public server so that it can be remotely fetched, but I could only find solutions to load into my own server.

Also, referencing the font within the project folders does not work, and I cannot understand why. I think it may be some streamlit hidden functioning.
